# How would i group an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to group this array. please help me..

```
Array
(
    [0] => dghfdih@hjuh.cvh
    [1] => dghfdih@hjuh.cvh
    [2] => dghfdih@hjuh.cvh
)
```

And my expected output is

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => dghfdih@hjuh.cvh

    )
```

Comment: _I want to group this array_ What does that mean? Group on what criteria? all elements are the same... what have you tried?

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => dghfdih@hjuh.cvh
   
)

Comment: Do you mean [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)?

Comment: You want to remove duplicate items..?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you wish to remove duplicates, luckily PHP has a function called `array_unique`

Use it like so:

```
$array = array( "dghfdih@hjuh.cvh", "dghfdih@hjuh.cvh", "dghfdih@hjuh.cvh" );

$array = array_unique( $array );
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) which will remove duplicates from the array.

```
<?php
// Assuming your array is stored as $arr
$arr = array(
    'dghfdih@hjuh.cvh',
    'dghfdih@hjuh.cvh',
    'dghfdih@hjuh.cvh'
);
// Remove the duplicates
$arr = array_unique($arr);
// Print to test
echo '<pre>'.var_export($arr, TRUE).'</pre>';
```